# Mouseenter event for firing

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to control a two-level menu bar through jQuery. The problem is that my `mouseenter` event is not firing.

Here's my HTML:

```
<ul class="top-level-menu">
        <li>Employees
            <ul class="second-level-menu">
                <li>Add new employee</li>
                <li>Edit employee details</li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>Attendance
            <ul class="second-level-menu">
                <li>View report</li>
                <li>Upload attendance</li>
            </ul>

        </li>

        <li>Broadcast</li>
        <li>Log out</li>
    </ul>
```

And the jQuery:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('.second-level-menu').hide();
            console.log("Hidden!\n");

            $('.first-level-menu').mouseenter(function(){
                console.log("Mouse enter\n");
                $(".second-level-menu", this).show();
            });

            $(".first-level-menu").mouseleave(function(){
                $(".second-level-menu", this).hide();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

There's no CSS as of now. Now, I'm getting the "Hidden!" message on console, which shows that the script is getting called, but nothing happens when I move my mouse onto the top-level items.

What's wrong?

Comment: And what should happen? I don't see any `'.first-level-menu'` element

Comment: There is no `.first-level-menu` in your `html` code. Do you mean `$('.top-level-menu').mouse...

Comment: How freaking embarrassing! :( I wrote the wrong name! Well, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @dotslash I posted an answer. Review it please... :-)

Comment: @IonicăBizău Just did. I wasn't allowed to accept an answer until now. Thanks for the help! :-)

Comment: @dotslash Yeah, I know. :-) You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`first-level-menu` class doesn't exist in HTML code. Add it to `ul` element:

```
<ul class="top-level-menu first-level-menu">...</ul>
```

Another fix is in the selector: select `li` elements instead of `ul`:

```
$('.first-level-menu li').mouseenter(function () {
    console.log("Mouse enter\n");
    $(".second-level-menu", this).show();
});
```

`this` will be the list element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.second-level-menu').hide();
  console.log("Hidden!\n");

  $('.first-level-menu li').mouseenter(function() {
    console.log("Mouse enter\n");
    $(".second-level-menu", this).show();
  });

  $(".first-level-menu li").mouseleave(function() {
    $(".second-level-menu", this).hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="top-level-menu first-level-menu">
  <li>Employees
    <ul class="second-level-menu">
      <li>Add new employee</li>
      <li>Edit employee details</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Attendance
    <ul class="second-level-menu">
      <li>View report</li>
      <li>Upload attendance</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Broadcast</li>
  <li>Log out</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<body>
<ul class="top-level-menu">
        <li class="first-level-menu">Employees
            <ul class="second-level-menu">
                <li>Add new employee</li>
                <li>Edit employee details</li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>Attendance
            <ul class="second-level-menu">
                <li>View report</li>
                <li>Upload attendance</li>
            </ul>

        </li>

        <li>Broadcast</li>
        <li>Log out</li>
    </ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

            $('.second-level-menu').hide();
            console.log("Hidden!\n");

            $('.first-level-menu').mouseenter(function(){
                console.log("Mouse enter\n");
                $(".second-level-menu", this).show();
            });

            $(".first-level-menu").mouseleave(function(){
                $(".second-level-menu", this).hide();
            });
        });
</script>
</body>
```

You don't have first-level-menu in your html.
So mouseenter and mouseleave does not work.
I have posted as an example working code

Comment: Thanks! Noticed that almost as soon I posted it here. XD